# find largest number in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create code that takes 2 arrays and then returns the largest value between the two.

```
public class LargestInt
{
    public static int largeValue(int 1[])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1.length; i++)
```

Comment: `else if (largest2 > largest1) return ..` what if `largest2 == largest1`? What should be returned?

Comment: @D.Hoffman You need to *something* in the case that they are equal. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: No one mentioned `IntStream.concat (IntStream.of(arr1), IntStream.of(arr2)).max()` ?

Answer (score 4):

You handle these two cases :

```
    if (largest1 > largest2)
        return largest1;

    else if (largest2 > largest1)
        return largest2;
```

But it doesn't handle the `else` case that is     `largest2 == largest1`.

As a method returns something (no `void` method), the compiler always ensures that all branches provides a `return` statement.

To address it, you may simply keep it :

```
if (largest1 > largest2)
    return largest1;
```

add as last statement :

`return largest2;`

As if `largest1 > largest2` is not true, it means necessary that `largest1 <= largest2`.

It would give so :

```
if (largest1 > largest2)
    return largest1;

 return largest2;
```

Comment: It would be simpler to reduce all of this to a simple `if-else` and use the fact that `<` and `>=` are complementary. Same outcome with less code.

Comment: @Paul Right. In fact,  I hesitated to write that. I didn't do as I though that it could be more complicated for the OP understanding: its root problem being the method return concept. But whatever you are right. Improving code matters.

Comment: I rather meant it as an addendum to the answer. Just a small hint to produce readable and simple code.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the common return value ie the case both arrays have largest number. Please find the below code to solve your issue. I have not optimized your code; just corrected it as requested by you.

```
 package com.stackoverflow.examples;

    /*I am trying to create code that takes 2 arrays, in my case "A" and "B", and then returns the largest value between the two. In my code below for example it should return 6. What i have so far finds the largest value of A which is labeled "largest1" and then get the largest from B which is "largest2". I'm now stuck however with the if and else if statements. The program says i'm missing a return statement. Anyone know what my issue may be? Thanks for any input!
    */
    public class LargestInt
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] A = {0,5,2};
            int[] B = {6,4,1};

            System.out.println(maxValue(A, B));
        }

        public static int maxValue(int A[], int B[])
        {
            int largest1 = A[0];
            int largest2 = B[0];

            for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            {
                if(A[i] > largest1)
                    largest1 = A[i];   
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
            {
               if(B[i] > largest2)
                    largest2 = B[i];   
            }

            if (largest1 > largest2)
                return largest1;

            else if (largest2 > largest1)
                return largest2;
            return largest2;
        }
    }
```

Please find the below code to solve your issue. I have done the same logic in completely different way.

```
 package com.stackoverflow.examples;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LargestInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = { 0, 15, 25 };
        int[] B = { 6, 4, 115 };
        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);         
        System.out.println((A[A.length - 1] >= B[B.length - 1]) ? A[A.length - 1] : B[B.length - 1]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This code won't find the maximum, if it occurs in both `A` and `B`. E.g.: `A = {1, 3, 5}, B = {2, 4, 5}` produces `null`, while the correct output would be 5.

Comment: Yeah i just wanted to specify that return is must at end not within the if/else so only i commented like " 

Please find the above code to solve your issue. I have not optimized your code; just corrected it as requested by you."

Comment: You should A) explicitly state what you did and why you did it, not just dump a few lines of code B) post working code. This will improve the quality of the answer and in general pays off in the form of well-received posts.

Comment: ok i have added the correct working code i totally agree what you say

Answer (score 1):

change the else if to just an else which would mean return the second one if it is larger or equal to the first. You need to return in every case and you don't return if the largest in each array equals each other. This will fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could change to an easier way, using only one `maxValue`

```
int maxValue= A[0];

for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{
    if(A[i] > maxValue)
        maxValue = A[i];   
}

for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
{
   if(B[i] > maxValue)
        maxValue = B[i];   
}
return maxValue;
```

---

Using latest API Stream, you can do it like this too :

```
public static int maxValue(int A[], int B[]) {
    return Stream.<int[]>of(A,B).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).max().getAsInt();
}
```

It will iterate over the 2 `arrays`, then over the `values` of both array, and then find `max`

Answer (score 1):

Simple issue:-

Here

```
if (largest1 > largest2)
    return largest1;

else if (largest2 > largest1)
    return largest2;
```

what if `largest1 == largest2` then ?? You have not defined this condition.

So either define it or just do following. Replace this  code with following code.

```
return largest1 > largest2 ? largest1 : largest2;
```

Or

```
if (largest1 > largest2)
    return largest1;

return largest2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the last line(since you are missing the third condition)

```
if (largest1 >= largest2)
    return largest1;

else if (largest2 > largest1)
    return largest2;
```

and your code will run all fine.

EDIT- even more short, using ternary operator

```
return largest1 >= largest2 ? largest1 : largest2
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way of doing this you could add those arrays into another, sort it and get the last value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {0, 5, 2};
    int[] B = {6, 4, 1};

    System.out.println(maxValue(A, B));
}

public static int maxValue(int a[], int b[]) {
    int aLen = a.length;
    int bLen = b.length;
    int[] c= new int[aLen+bLen];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);

    Arrays.sort(c);
    return c[c.length-1];
}
```

Output:

> 6

Comment: This method adds unnecessary space and time complexity. It can be done in O(1) extra space and O(a+b) time complexity